# Capture first character of last group of 1s in a binary series

Tags: t-sql

I have a series something like this:

```
Month   J F M A M J J A S O N D
Status  1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Using t-SQL, I am trying to capture the month corresponding to the first 1 in the last group of 1s, i.e., September in this example.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp1

    ;WITH PARTITIONED1 AS

    (SELECT         , t0.ID
            , t0.Year_Month
            , t0.Status
            , LAST_VALUE(t0.Year_Month) OVER (PARTITION BY t0.ID ORDER BY t0.Year_Month) AS D_YM
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t0.ID ORDER BY t0.Year_Month) AS rn1

    FROM #Temp0 t0
```

However, this just returns the first occurence of a 1; January here.

I really can't figure this one out, so any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What are the data types of your table?

Comment: Months are varchar(7), Status is tinyint.

Comment: Is there any sorting column? SQL Server does not have any implict sort order, so the *first* or *last* doesn't mean anything without an `ORDER BY`...

Comment: Yes - sorry - this is just an excerpt.  It is ordered by ID, Year_Month, and there should be a where Status = 1 at the end of the code, although the ordering is performed in a previous stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carefull with

> although the ordering is performed in a previous stage

The previous sorting does **not guarantee** the later processing!

Try something like this. It is a very simple approach where you rely on gapless IDs:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,Mnth VARCHAR(100),[Status] TINYINT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('J',1)
,('F',0) 
,('M',0) 
,('A',1) 
,('M',0) 
,('J',1) 
,('J',0) 
,('A',0) 
,('S',1) 
,('O',1) 
,('N',1) 
,('D',1);

SELECT a.*
FROM @tbl AS a
WHERE a.ID=(SELECT MAX(b.ID)+1 FROM @tbl AS b WHERE b.[Status]=0)
```

Comment: Yes, I kind of realized that assuming the ordering was carried through was a bit dumb as I was typing it...  Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: Works like a dream!

Comment: Done!  Thanks for the tips - as you can probably tell, I don't use SO very often ;)

Comment: Apologies for bothering you again with this, but I now need to run multiple accounts through the script, all with associated data in the format of my original question.  I've tried 

`where acc_no in ('123456', '234567')`

but obviously the code just returns the first status 1 from the last group of whichever of the accounts fits the bill.

Do you know how I would go about getting results for both accounts?

I have tried various combos of CASE and grouping, but with no joy so far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Zephyr, please avoid chameleon questions. One principle on SO is: *one issue - one question*... Please start a new question, with fitting sample data and expected output. Place a link to this question and you might place a comment here to give me an alert...

Comment: Okie dokie - will do so after my lunch - and again thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: Done!

Capture First Character of Last Group of 1s in a Binary Series Part II: Multiple IDs

Thanks for all of your assistance :)

Answer (score 1):

this can also be used :

```
select top 1 Month from table t where Status=1
and not exists
(select id from table t1 where stat=0 and t1.id>t.id)
order by t.id
```

Comment: Yes, I can see that would work.  I think I somehow really over-complicated the problem!

Comment: Yup - it also does the job.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I might have overcomplicated this but not knowing the table structure I put the below together:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp1
CREATE TABLE #Temp1
(
    Jan int,
    Feb int,
    Mar int,
    Apr int,
    May int,
    June int, 
    July int ,
    Aug int,
    Sep int,
    Oct int,
    Nov int,
    Dec int
)
insert into #temp1
select 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#monthTranslate') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #monthTranslate
create table #monthTranslate
(
    MonthValue varchar(50), 
    MonthInt int
)
insert into  #monthTranslate
select 'Jan',1
union all select 'Feb',2 
union all select 'Mar',3
union all select 'Apr',4 
union all select 'May',5
union all select 'June',6
union all select 'July',7 
union all select 'Aug',8
union all select 'Sep',9 
union all select 'OCt',10 
union all select 'Nov',11
union all select 'Dec',12



--find the max month w\ 0 and add 1... becareful on null, it might return January incorrectly.  I'd check for that in a a case statement
select  max(b.MonthInt)+1
from  
(
    select
        MonthPassVal, months  , t.MonthInt  
    from 
    (
    select Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, June, July, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec
    from #temp1
    ) as r
    Unpivot
    (
        MonthPassVal for Months 
            in (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, June, July, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec)
    ) as u
    inner join #monthTranslate t
        on t.MonthValue = months
)  as b 
where
    MonthPassVal=0
```

Comment: LOL.  I think I over-complicated it in that you may already have the data unpivoted.  It was hard to tell from the original post.